# immutable.js get keys from map/hash

Tags: immutable.js

I want to retrieve keys() from the following Immutable Map:

```
var map = Immutable.fromJS({"firstKey": null, "secondKey": null });
console.log(JSON.stringify(map.keys()));
```

I would expect the output:

```
["firstKey", "secondKey"]
```

However this outputs:

```
{"_type":0,"_stack":{"node":{"ownerID":{},"entries":[["firstKey",null],["secondKey",null]]},"index":0}}
```

How to do it properly?

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/57/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Although this question got answered a while ago, here is a little update:

**ES6 Solution:**

```
const [ ...keys ] = map.keys();
```

---

**Pre ES6 Solution:**

```
var keys = map.keySeq().toArray();
```

Comment: ES6 is ES2015. Do you mean pre-ES2015?

Comment: Changed. Thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 39):

This is how ImmutableJS object looks like.

If you want to get:

```
["firstKey", "secondKey"]
```

You need to do:

```
console.log(map.keySeq().toArray())
```

Comment: You can also use the generic `toJS()` to convert immutable types back to normal js objects or arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly just answering my own question that lead me here, but I found `mapKeys()` which will gives you access to keys in a regular loop. It seems a bit more "the right way". (The docs are so vague, who knows!)

eg:

```
Map({ a: 1, b: 2 }).mapKeys((key, value) => console.log(key, value))
// a 1
// b 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice with Immutable.js is to use Immutable data structures and minimize conversions to JavaScript types. For this problem we can use [keySeq()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/keySeq), which returns a new `Seq.Indexed` (an ordered indexed list of values) of the keys of this [Map](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map). We then can then set a [List](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) to those values and assign that List to a variable for use later. Here is an example of how this solution could be implemented:

```
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';

const exampleMap = Map({ a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 });

const keys = List(exampleMap.keySeq()); // List [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```